# Picasso RequestHandler - Decrypt file before load image

Tags: android, picasso

All my images are encrypted in Android file system. When I need to show them, I need to decrypt, generate the bitmap and then delete the file. I'm trying to use Picasso to load my images. I created an **RequestHandler** to decrypt and load image.

**RequestHandler** accepts two types of result:

**1.** the bitmap or **2.** a stream.

I'm trying to return the stream. That way Picasso can load images using the best practices, prevent out of memory. I created an custom Stream class and override the Dispose() method to delete the decrypted file after use.

**The problem is:** The stream is not disposing, neither closing, after the image is loaded, and I can't for automatic dispose by GAC (I'm using Xamarin/C#).  **Any ideas?  What can I do?**

**UPDATE (19/01/17):** I found out a small bug in my code and after fixing it, my problem was solved. But here is my custom **RequestHandler** for future reference... **EncryptedFileStream** is my custom stream that wraps the original stream and delete the decrypted file on **Dispose()**.

```
public class EncryptedFilenameRequestHandler : RequestHandler
{
  private readonly Context _context;
  private readonly ICriptoService _criptoService;

  public EncryptedFilenameRequestHandler(Context context, ICriptoService criptoService)
  {
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    if (criptoService == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(criptoService));

    _context = context;
    _criptoService = criptoService;
  }

  public override bool CanHandleRequest(Request request)
  {
    var uri = request.Uri;
    return string.Compare(uri.Scheme, Constantes.AppSchema, true) == 0 &&
      string.Compare(uri.Authority, Constantes.Host, true) == 0 &&
      string.Compare(uri.Path, "/loadimagem/filename/encrypted", true) == 0;
  }

  public override Result Load(Request request, int networkPolicy)
  {
    string password = request.Uri.GetQueryParameter("p");
    string encryptedFilename = request.Uri.GetQueryParameter("f");
    string decryptedFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppEnviroment.GetTempDirectory(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(encryptedFilename) || !File.Exists(encryptedFilename))
      return null;

    _criptoService.Decrypt(encryptedFilename, decryptedFilename, password);

    //retorna um stream para leitura do arquivo descriptografado
    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(decryptedFilename));
    var stream = new EncryptedFileStream(decryptedFilename, _context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri));
    return new Result(stream, Picasso.LoadedFrom.Disk);
  }

}
```

Comment: What does your custom stream class look like? It's hard to diagnose the problem without any idea what your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a small bug in my code and, after fixing it, my problem was solved. The code for **EncryptedFilenameRequestHandler** posted in the question is working without any problem.